# fetch rows having discontinuities in date ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data as below and want to fetch the rows whose end date is not same as the starting date of the next row.

in this case I should get the output with rows 3 and 4

```
    start date  end date
1   11/6/2017   11/13/2017
2   11/13/2017  12/26/2017
3   12/26/2017  1/8/2018
4   10/22/2018  2/25/2019
5   2/25/2019   3/4/2019
6   3/4/2019    3/11/2019
```

Comment: What's your RDBMS?  Do you only have your date fields, or do you have a sequential ID field?  It sounds like you might need to use window functions, of which documentation and related SO questions and answers abound.

Comment: im using SQL server and I have a key with sequential id.

Comment: Do you have overlapping date ranges or they are all different?

Comment: I have overlapping date ranges and that's how it is excepted to be except the rows 3 and 4 above

Answer (score 0):

Use `lead()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, lead(start_date) over (order by start_date) as next_start_date
      from t
     ) t
where end_date <> next_start_date
```

Comment: I want to display only the rows 3 and 4 in the example above andthis query is not working for the same

Comment: @Gordon is there any way other than lag just like checking rownum+1 for the next row each time a row is fetched i know rownum would not work but just an alternative similar to rownum

Comment: Also I just want to fetch the results of the data which is already available as above

Comment: As per the above lead query I am getting the below values, 
StartDate EndDate next_start_date
10/30/17 0:00.00 11/6/17 0:00.00 11/6/17 0:00.00

11/6/17 0:00.00 11/13/17 0:00.00 11/13/17 0:00.00

11/13/17 0:00.00 12/26/17 0:00.00 12/26/17 0:00.00

12/26/17 0:00.00 10/22/18 11:13.02 9/2/15 0:00.00

10/22/18 11:13.02 2/25/19 16:34.53 10/22/18 11:13.02

2/25/19 16:34.53 3/4/19 9:56.54 2/25/19 16:34.53

3/4/19 9:56.54 3/11/19 12:30.50 3/4/19 9:56.54

 and the next date is populated incorrectly when there is timestamp involved in the date .

Comment: @smyliepanda . . . This seems to do what you want, as asked in the question.  If your data is different from the question, you can try using `cast(<datecol> as date)`.  If that doesn't fix the problem, ask a *new* question with appropriate sample data and desired results.